# Only use radial force on some of the nodes D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvLf579a/282/)

I have colour coded the nodes and I wish for these nodes not to be effected by the radial force. Here is how I thought it may work :

```js
 function radial() {
      simulation
        .force("charge", d3.forceCollide().radius(10))
        .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) {
          if(d.id == 3){
             return null //dont effect these nodes
          }else
          if (d.id < 5) {
            return 100;
          } else {
            return 200;
          }
        }, width / 2, height / 2).strength(1))
      simulation.alpha(1).restart()    
    }
```

However, this seems that it just places them in the center and doesn't skip them. Is there another way to filter out these nodes so that the radial force doesn't move them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `null` on the force accessor, you're actually setting the radius of the circle for those nodes to (0,0). Per the docs:

[d3.forceRadial()](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceRadial)

> Creates a new positioning force towards a circle of the specified radius centered at ⟨x,y⟩. If x and y are not specified, they default to ⟨0,0⟩.

What you want to do, instead, is set the strength of the force to 0 for the corresponding nodes. You'll also want to turn off all of the other forces that you had set up when you initialized the simulation:

```
function radial() {
  simulation
    .force("charge", d3.forceCollide().radius(10))
    .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) {
        return d.id < 5 ? 100 : 200;
      }, width / 2, height / 2).strength(function(d) {
        // set radial force to 0 if it has the id we're looking for
        if(d.id == 3) return 0
        // otherwise keep the strength at 1
        else return 1
      })
    )
    // turning off previously set forces
    .force('link', null)
    .force('x', null)
    .force('y', null)
```

Comment: This looks great, however, i dont think its fully there. I still want the strength in the links. This is because, I have a network with curved links, here is a fiddle I put together a while back http://jsfiddle.net/gp0u5rLu/75/ notice the curve, this is curved using an intermediary node that the path is pulled towards and you can't see it. If I put your logic in place, the nodes stay in one place, nothing effects them, I still want them to be pulled if I pull a related node, I just dont want them in the radial layout. Hope that makes sense, really appreciate the help

Comment: If you don’t pass null for the link force, that should do what you’re describing. I interpreted from your question that you wanted to “freeze” the red nodes in place.